# SoapUI Maven plugin- executing multiple projects

Tags: maven-plugin, soapui, service-layer, automated-tests

I am working on converting an Ant execution of the SoapUI TestRunner to use the maven plugin and I cannot get a good answer on how to execute multiple projects using this plugin.

I found a forum post from 2010 on the Smartbear forum and there are a few approaches listed but none seem very workable (writing some script to invoke maven with different parameters or adding an execution for every project).

Are there any best practices for working around this? Or has anyone seen an inventive solution to this problem?

I would guess that this is a large scale problem...

[Here](http://www.soapui.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=3832&p=17539&hilit=multiple+projects+maven&sid=958b538e24a0e501533e74307801c72d#p17539) is the post I am refering to.

Comment: I had this problem.  I ended up writing my own maven plugin.  It was pretty simple to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I haven't gotten much of an answer anywhere.  So if you find this question here are your options.

- Multiple executions of the plugin
- Write a script to envoke maven multiple times
- Build your own maven plugin
- Use Ant to execute the testrunner.bat

The choice is yours.  I've decided to keep on using my Ant execution of soapui.  Here is a blog with an [example](http://thewonggei.wordpress.com/2010/06/23/some-thoughts-on-integrating-soapui-functional-tests-with-your-build/) of the ant execution.  Maybe one of these days i'll get around to writing my own plugin.  To be honest, the ant execution works really well. I've used ant to do a number of things after the tests (execute multiple projects, check for failures, etc).  Ant does seem to offer a nice solution to this, Maven's strict structure isn't really that great for something that isn't really a build anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to that in above this is an example code block for it.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-soapui-extension-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.6.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>soapUI1</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-multi</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectFiles>
                                <scan>
                                    <baseDirectory>/home/waruna/workspace/soapuitest/src/main/resources/projects</baseDirectory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>*.xml</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>**/*fail-*-soapui-project.xml</exclude>
                                        <exclude>**/composite-projects/**</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </scan>
                            </projectFiles>
                            <outputFolder>/home/waruna/workspace/soapuitest/src/main/resources/</outputFolder>
                            <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                            <useOutputFolderPerProject>true</useOutputFolderPerProject>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```