# Maven SoapUI plugin - how to execute 2 SoapUI test projects during Maven's lifecycle

Tags: unit-testing, maven-3, soapui, pom.xml

I have 2 different SoapUI test projects that I want to run during the build (I am using maven-soapui-plugin 3.6.1 and Maven 3 for that).
Currently all I can do is to execute only 1 project (see my pom.xml file)... Suppose I want to execute 2 SoapUI test projects and also control their execution order...
What is the correct syntax to do so ?

My current pom.xml file :

```
 <plugin>                                                                                                                      
     <groupId>eviware</groupId>                                                                                                
     <artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>                                                                              
     <version>3.6.1</version>                                                                                                  
     <configuration>                                                                                                           
      <projectFile>${project.basedir}\src\test\resources\soapui\Web-Service-automatic-testing-soapui-project.xml</projectFile> 
         <outputFolder>${project.basedir}\src\test\resources\soapui\output</outputFolder>                                      
         <junitReport>true</junitReport>                                                                                       
     </configuration>                                                                                                          
     <executions>                                                                                                              
         <execution>                                                                                                           
             <id>soapUI</id>                                                                                                   
             <!--Run as part of the test phase in the Maven lifecycle-->                                                       
             <phase>test</phase>                                                                                               
             <goals>                                                                                                           
                 <goal>test</goal>                                                                                             
             </goals>                                                                                                          
         </execution>                                                                                                          
     </executions>                                                                                                             
 </plugin>
```

Comment: I went through the same thing not too long ago, my question and solutions can be found here. An important note, I'm dealing with 300 + services. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184862/soapui-maven-plugin-executing-multiple-projects/9245939#9245939

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify multiple executions for SoapUI plugin. For example:

```
 <plugin>                                                                                                                      
     <groupId>eviware</groupId>                                                                                                
     <artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>                                                                              
     <version>3.6.1</version>                                                                                                  
     <configuration>                                      
         <outputFolder>${project.basedir}\src\test\resources\soapui\output</outputFolder>
         <junitReport>true</junitReport>
     </configuration>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <id>soapUI1</id>
             <phase>test</phase>
             <goals>
                 <goal>test</goal>
             </goals>
            <configuration>
              <projectFile>${project.basedir}\src\test\resources\soapui\Web-Service-automatic-testing-soapui-project1.xml</projectFile> 
            </configuration>
         </execution>                                                                                                          
         <execution>
             <id>soapUI2</id>
             <phase>test</phase>
             <goals>
                 <goal>test</goal>
             </goals>
            <configuration>
              <projectFile>${project.basedir}\src\test\resources\soapui\Web-Service-automatic-testing-soapui-project2.xml</projectFile> 
            </configuration>
         </execution>                                                                                                          
     </executions>                                                                                                             
 </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for that one - I'll try it. In which order they would be executed?

Comment: In the order you declared them. Also make sure they have unique execution ids.

Comment: Thank you. I have committed the changes and tomorrow morning (after the nightly build) I will see how it worked.

Comment: I'm trying the same for my project but it's not working. I checked with all the versions of this plugin.

Comment: What if you want to specify a specific testSuite? I put <build><plugins><plugin><configuration><testSuite>blabla</ ////> but it seems the same testCases are executed multiple times and out of order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui/maven-soapui-extension-plugin/4.6.4.1) plugin for above requirement. Given below is a code block for it.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-soapui-extension-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.6.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>soapUI1</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-multi</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectFiles>
                                <scan>
                                    <baseDirectory>/home/waruna/workspace/soapuitest/src/main/resources/projects</baseDirectory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>*.xml</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>**/*fail-*-soapui-project.xml</exclude>
                                        <exclude>**/composite-projects/**</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </scan>
                            </projectFiles>
                            <outputFolder>/home/waruna/workspace/soapuitest/src/main/resources/</outputFolder>
                            <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                            <useOutputFolderPerProject>true</useOutputFolderPerProject>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't go the maven route. use command line testrunner.sh and run all the tests in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Running soapui composite project from junit test

Only major issue for running SOAPUI project from junit tests is finding all correct dependency jars of SOAPUI.

I have created an uber jar of all required jars. This new jar is added below on GitHub code base in lib folder. This uber jar is compatible with Ready API 1.5.0 version. (Note that, I have tried it with rest API testing with composite project)

Junit test case takes composite project path and runs all test steps from each test case.

Running tests at step level helps to debug if build fails.

http://www.learnteachandlearn.com/2015/12/executing-composite-soapui-project-from.html

https://github.com/suyogchoudhari/soapui-junit