# Include jar to SoapUI maven

Tags: maven, jar, maven-plugin, soapui

I wrote my own library to maven. I include the jar file like this:
http://www.soapui.org/extension-plugins/old-style-extensions/developing-old-style-extensions.html
and everything is OK.

But, i wanna run my SoapUI projekt in maven. How i can include this library?

Comment: See: [Soap UI maven plugin](http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html)

Comment: Related: [how to execute 2 SoapUI test projects during Maven's lifecycle](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9907607/55075)

Comment: The only way to accomplish this is to repackage SoapUI with your extension. Start here: https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an `ext` folder inside you maven project's root, i.e. where your pom.xml is.
The put your compiled jar in this folder (as you've already done in your `<SoapUI_installation_dir>\bin\ext` directory) in order this jar to be available to the SoapUI runner when it is run via maven.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED:

To include a soap ui project in maven include the plugin in your POM and configure it with the SoapUI project file (See below)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
    <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <projectFile>simple-test-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Looks like this plugin is not available in maven central, so you will have to include the plugin repository like so (in your pom or the settings.xml)

```
<pluginRepository>
    <id>smartbear-sweden-plugin-repository</id>
    <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
</pluginRepository>
```

More information can be found here - [Soap UI maven plugin](http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html)

There is also another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907607/maven-soapui-plugin-how-to-execute-2-soapui-test-projects-during-mavens-lifec)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @kenorb sure, but does the plugin not provide a way to run the soap ui project through maven? its not a critique or a clarification.

Comment: @jrao77 You should expand your answer further as it's marked as low quality one, therefore it's a risk that it would be removed soon.

Comment: The OP *modified* SoapUI, and is asking how to include his *modifications* in a SoapUI Maven project.